# Laravel 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

As title said, I got error 403 (title of page) on Laravel project. Locally, it's working, but when I'm trying to put it live, on a web-host/my domain it gives me:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I deleted `.htaccess` file from public folder, and nothing happened.
Any solutions?

Comment: What is your folder structure? i.e. where is `laravel/app` in relation to `httpdocs` ?

Comment: What are the ownership and access permissions on the directory and files?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a project, clearing the cookies solved it.

Answer (score 5):

Your `.htaccess` is not parsed by apache because `AllowOverride All` directive is missing inside virtualhost configuration. `.htaccess` file is required for Laravel. Put back it. Then change apache virtual host configuration on server to allow `.htaccess`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.net
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example3"
    <Directory /var/www/html/example3>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Change your virtualhost like this and restart apache by `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Replace `www.example.net` and  `/var/www/html/example3` with correct details.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using your own Request, change the authorize function to return true:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

As simple as that!

Answer (score 2):

You can try these commands.

```
sudo chmod -R gu+w project_folder
sudo chmod -R guo+w project_folder

chmod -R 775 storage/
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: Interesting reminder, though, didn't solve it to me.