# my website loads on http but with https its giving 403 error laravel 5.8

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5.8

My website loads well on http but when i enable ssl and with https it give me 403 Forbidden Access
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I have tries many different htaccess codes but I wasn't able to solve this problem.

My htaccess on my documnet root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I keep on getting 403 Forbidden access error and if I change something in htaccess It gives me 500 Internal Server Error or 404 Page Not Found

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010415/laravel-403-forbidden-error

Comment: sorry, Kevin but Its not because my website is working well without SSL.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, HTTP works well, but has an error on HTTPS. @Manoj have you fixed it?

Comment: yes @Mr.Unknown, I recommend check your error logs on laravel and apache/nginx

Comment: Apache2: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration' 
I'm using apache. Is this looks familiar to you?

Comment: No its not, but check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration